# Scalac 2.12 fails to resolve overloaded methods with multiple argument lists when using kafka-streams-scala

Tags: scala, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

When using kafka-streams-scala, the porting of lightbend kafka-streams-scala, with Scala 2.12, we are experiencing a strange problem with the compiler which can't handle correctly invocation to an overloaded method

```
import org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.Consumed
import org.apache.kafka.streams.scala.StreamsBuilder
import org.apache.kafka.streams.scala.kstream.KTable

object FailingExample {


  private val builder = new StreamsBuilder()

  class MyClass

  class MyClass2

  class MyClass3

  implicit val consumedMyClass1: Consumed[String,MyClass] = null

  implicit val consumedMyClass2: Consumed[String,MyClass2] = null

  val table:KTable[String,MyClass] = builder.table[String,MyClass]("myTopic1")
  val table1:KTable[String,MyClass2] = builder.table[String,MyClass2]("myTopic1")

  table.join(table1)(
    (myClass:MyClass, myClass2:MyClass2) => new MyClass3
  )
```

The compiler fails with

```
[error] /Users/edmondoporcu1/Development/credimi/user-preferences/user-preferences-salesforce-updater/src/main/scala/com/credimi/kafka/FailingExample.scala:25:9: ambiguous reference to overloaded definition,
[error] both method join in class KTable of type [VO, VR](other: org.apache.kafka.streams.scala.kstream.KTable[String,VO])(joiner: (com.credimi.kafka.FailingExample.MyClass, VO) => VR, materialized: org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.Materialized[String,VR,org.apache.kafka.streams.scala.ByteArrayKeyValueStore])org.apache.kafka.streams.scala.kstream.KTable[String,VR]
[error] and  method join in class KTable of type [VO, VR](other: org.apache.kafka.streams.scala.kstream.KTable[String,VO])(joiner: (com.credimi.kafka.FailingExample.MyClass, VO) => VR)org.apache.kafka.streams.scala.kstream.KTable[String,VR]
[error] match argument types (org.apache.kafka.streams.scala.kstream.KTable[String,com.credimi.kafka.FailingExample.MyClass2])
[error]   table.join(table1)(
```

However, this doesn't make much sense, since we are passing only an argument in the second argument list, and therefore the compiler should not have any ambiguity.
We include for reference the two methods in org.apache.kafka.streams.scala.kstream.Ktable :

```
  /**
   * Join records of this [[KTable]] with another [[KTable]]'s records using non-windowed inner equi join.
   *
   * @param other  the other [[KTable]] to be joined with this [[KTable]]
   * @param joiner a function that computes the join result for a pair of matching records
   * @return a [[KTable]] that contains join-records for each key and values computed by the given joiner,
   * one for each matched record-pair with the same key
   * @see `org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.KTable#join`
   */
  def join[VO, VR](other: KTable[K, VO])(joiner: (V, VO) => VR): KTable[K, VR] =
    inner.join[VO, VR](other.inner, joiner.asValueJoiner)

  /**
   * Join records of this [[KTable]] with another [[KTable]]'s records using non-windowed inner equi join.
   *
   * @param other  the other [[KTable]] to be joined with this [[KTable]]
   * @param joiner a function that computes the join result for a pair of matching records
   * @param materialized  a `Materialized` that describes how the `StateStore` for the resulting [[KTable]]
   *                      should be materialized. 
   * @return a [[KTable]] that contains join-records for each key and values computed by the given joiner,
   * one for each matched record-pair with the same key
   * @see `org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.KTable#join`
   */
  def join[VO, VR](other: KTable[K, VO])(
    joiner: (V, VO) => VR,
    materialized: Materialized[K, VR, ByteArrayKeyValueStore]
  ): KTable[K, VR] =
    inner.join[VO, VR](other.inner, joiner.asValueJoiner, materialized)
```

Comment: I'm wondering if the inferencer might get confused by potential partial application of `join` as it returns a lambda in both cases...?

Comment: What version are you using? We fixed some bug in 2.1 release in the Scala API.

Comment: Seem like you hit https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-7301 -- fixed in 2.0.1 and 2.1.0.

Comment: That's correct, it is also a bug in the scala compiler. If you provide an answer I will accept your answer